# jQuery Ajax Appears to be POSTing but can't catch the values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What am I missing here?

I am trying to pass an array of strings via a jQuery AJAX POST.

```
var json = JSON.stringify( selectedTags );
var data = json;
```

...

```
var apiCall = $.ajax({
    url: "service-getemails-multiple.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST"
    //beforeSend: alert(data)
}).done(function(data) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
    var html = '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 90%" id="emailsTextbox">' + data + '</textarea>';
    html += data;
    html += "\" target=\"new\">Send Email</a></p>";
    $("#dialog").html(html);
    $("#emailsTextbox").focus();
    $("#emailsTextbox").select();
});
```

My catcher ("service-getemails-multiple.php") is currently extremely simple and I don't understand why it's failing to catch the AJAX request (POST).

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

In Firebug, I can see the values being passed under XHR/Post as parameters and under source. If I uncomment "beforeSend: alert(data)" that alerts the values just fine.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure there's no redirect or other funkiness occuring on the server?  what does `var_dump($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"])` show?

Comment: Just a guess but it's not that the variable is named data too? Have you tried: data: JSON.stringify( selectedTags );

Comment: No redirect I have put on... it's IIS on Windows (don't get me started) and have had weird issues before, but I can't think of anything in this case. var dump on REQUEST_METHOD shows: string(4) "POST"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify( selectedTags );
var thedata = json;
....
var apiCall = $.ajax({
    url: "service-getemails-multiple.php",
    data: {mydata: thedata},
    type: "POST"
    //beforeSend: alert(data)
}).done(function(data) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
    var html = '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 90%" id="emailsTextbox">' + data + '</textarea>';
    html += data;
    html += "\" target=\"new\">Send Email</a></p>";
    $("#dialog").html(html);
    $("#emailsTextbox").focus();
    $("#emailsTextbox").select();
});
```

Comment: the only thing I changed was that I changed the `data: data` to `data: {mydata: thedata}`. ajax expects the data value to be an object. if you want to pass more stuff you just can do it like that: `data: {mydata: thedata, secondValue: 'string', thirdValue: thirdVar...}` with that there is also no need to encode everything into json...

Answer (score 1):

I think the function is confused about `data: data` part.

Try this

```
var apiCall = $.ajax({
    url: "service-getemails-multiple.php",
    data: json, // <!-- Use json instead. Its the same thing
    type: "POST"
    //beforeSend: alert(data)
}).done(function(data) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
    var html = '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 90%" id="emailsTextbox">' + data + '</textarea>';
    html += data;
    html += "\" target=\"new\">Send Email</a></p>";
    $("#dialog").html(html);
    $("#emailsTextbox").focus();
    $("#emailsTextbox").select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this { dataType: 'json'}

it will look like That
**
var apiCall = $.ajax({
    url: "service-getemails-multiple.php",
    data: data,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    //beforeSend: alert(data)
}).done(function(data) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();
    var html = '' + data + '';
    html += data;
    html += "\" target=\"new\">Send Email

";
    $("#dialog").html(html);
    $("#emailsTextbox").focus();
    $("#emailsTextbox").select();
});**